# Close an open OneNote application using VBS

Tags: vbscript, onenote

I'm trying to close an open OneNote application on a user's computer using VB Script. However, I cannot seem to get it to work. I need to close any open OneNotes before I run the rest of the VBS file. So far I've tried this, but doesn't work for OneNote.

```
Set oNote= CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oNote.Exec "onenote"
oNote.Terminate
```

This is another code I've tried. Neither work.

```
Set oNote= CreateObject("onenote")
oNote.Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this way to kill `Onenote.exe` process

```
Option Explicit
Dim Process
Process = "Onenote.exe"
Call Kill(Process)
'****************************************************
Sub Kill(Process)
    Dim Ws,Command,Execution
    Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "& Process &""
    Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
    Set Ws = Nothing
End Sub 
'****************************************************
```

Or by this way :

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strProcessKill 
strComputer = "."
strProcessKill = "'Onenote.exe'" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & strProcessKill )
For Each objProcess in colProcess
    objProcess.Terminate(1)
Next
```